# Autowired NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

Я только разбираюсь со спрингом, поэтому не совсем понимаю как работает.
Итак я сделал все как в туториале [firstapp](https://github.com/marciomarinho/firstapp) и все работает.

Добавил свой контроллер и он почти работает.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/transactionlist")
public class TransactionController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listTransactions(Model model){

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setRepository();

        model.addAttribute("posts", repository.findAll());
        return "posts/transactionlist";
    }
}
```

NPE вылетает в следующем простом джава классе, который я сделал для работы с SQLite базой:

```
@Component
public class Sample
{
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository; // вот здесь 

    public void setRepository() {
        System.out.println(repository);
        repository.save(new Post( "testpost" ));
    }
}
```

У меня вопрос - почему не срабатывает автопривязка? Можно ли её (автопривязку) использовать в простых джава классах? Т.е. удалить аннотацию компонент из моего класса Sample? в моем случае оно не работает ни так, ни так. 
context.xml у меня нет, т.е. все на аннотациях, как и в исходном проекте.

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация `@Autowired` работает только в бинах. Поэтому `Sample` должен быть помечен аннотацией `@Component` (или аналогичной) и должен создаваться не вручную оператором `new`, а контейнером Spring.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/transactionlist")
public class TransactionController {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private Sample sample;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listTransactions(Model model){
        sample.setRepository();

        model.addAttribute("posts", repository.findAll());
        return "posts/transactionlist";
    }
}
```

Comment: ок, я перестал создавать класс Сэмпл и никак к нему не обращаюсь, но оставил в статик блоке обращение к переменной репозитори, чтобы протестировать его работу, и теперь приложение падает уже на стадии запуска, потому что не может сделать бин Сэмпл, потому что обращение к репозитори также выдает нулл.

Comment: так, похоже что статик блоками нельзя вызывать биновые объекты. Да, сделал как вы предлагаете, и все заработало.

Comment: Чтобы Spring знал, что бин нужно создать, надо или внедрить его куда-нибудь с помощью аннотации @Autowired или получить его из контекста вызовом `applicationContext.getBean("beanName")`. Лучше первое.

Comment: т.е. ответ на вопрос про работу с биновыми объектами из обычных классов - нет, так не получится

Comment: Да, не получится.